# How to save a state of a variable in android app and use it

Tags: android

I have an android app which was built on eclipse. What i am currently doing is going through set of question in xml file randomly to ask. Xml file looks like this:

```
<item>
    <ques></ques>
    <option1></option1>
    <option2></option2>
    <option3></option3>
    <ans></ans>
    <level>1</level>
</item>
<item>
    <ques></ques>
    <option1></option1>
    <option2></option2>
    <option3></option3>
    <ans></ans>
    <level>1</level>
</item>
<item>
    <ques></ques>
    <option1></option1>
    <option2></option2>
    <option3></option3>
    <ans></ans>
    <level>2</level>
</item>
```

so on....

Right now i am selecting question from level one randomly. Like there are 50 question in level 1 and 50 in level 2. I want to select question in order now. Like start from the top to bottom. Like if user A logs in plays the game he is being asked question a and b from level 1. Then he closes the game and logs back again so he should see c and d now.

My problem is how can this state be saved in android? Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you could do is, is for each level have it numbered

For level 1 question a int variable to keep track of the question the user is on. You could have

```
int questionNumber;
```

in your method declare for each question the user gets to

```
 questionNumber++;
```

Now when the player leaves the activity or logs out of the app.

Put the question number in the [Shared Preference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) like this..

```
  SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("questionNumber", questionNumber);
    editor.commit(); // Very important
```

Now to pull the number out just use..

```
  SharedPreferences app_preferences = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // Get the value for the run counter
    questionNumber = app_preferences.getInt("questionNumber", 0);// The 0 is there for if the user hastn played before it is set to 0 automatically or you can set it to 1
```

EDIT:

Also you could have a Variable that keeps track of the Level the user is on such as

```
int userLevel;
```

And just save it to shared preference as you did before.

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences to store and retrieve values... very easy to use.(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use shared preferences. See the guide topic [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for pointers to the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Store it on the Android device: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html