# boolean won't stay on the right input when i kill my app or reboot the device

Tags: java, android

im building a app, found a java part that lets me show an activity only at first start.
this works but when i kill the app or reboot my phone it goes back, can anyone help me out with this?

im using this in my main activity (Toolz.java)

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Prefs.firststart == false) {
            setContentView(R.layout.toolz);
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, First.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
          }


    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
  }
```

and i added this to First.java

```
    Prefs.firststart=false;
```

and i made the Prefs.java and added this

```
public class Prefs {
    public static boolean firststart = true;
}
```

Comment: I think what you want is [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: The static fields will be preserved until the Application killed, e.g when the Activity is out of sight and no Services running the Application can be killed already. If you restart the device all Applications will restart. Thus you need a permanent storage. For your goals the SharedPrefernces will be the best.

Comment: thnx for the responces on sharedpreferences yall, and doctoror on the post before your edit, things also can be learned by asking stuff to ppl. im trying to find out most stuff by searching and dont wanna ask to fast but i was just stuck on this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the app restarts all your code will start from the starting point (i.e `Prefs.firststart` will be set to true). Instead, you need to make a persistent variable that is saved throughout sessions. If you're using a DB you could use that, or you could use the built-in `SharedPreferences`, as such:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences prefs = this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (prefs.contains("started")) {
        setContentView(R.layout.toolz);
    } else {
        //Add the preference:
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("started",true);
        editor.apply();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, First.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
      }


}
```

Comment: Perfect i started on searching and trying with sharedpreferences but then i noticed your answer and tried this and it works perfectly thnx

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) instead o static variable for saving data which also available when app killed  or device reboot.

you can see following tutorial how we use SharedPreferences for saving and reading data from SharedPreferences

[Shared Preferences](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you kill your app, the values are going to reset to their initial values.  Your boolean will be equal to true.  I suggest saving the state of the variable using SharedPreferences.  Check out this other question someone asked about saving.

[How to save a state of a variable in android app and use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392029/how-to-save-a-state-of-a-variable-in-android-app-and-use-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
//**** First start *****

//you get the prefs for your app using a pref name 
String PREFS_NAME = "myAppPrefs";
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
//persist the boolean value in preferences using a key-value approach
editor.putBoolean("pref_app_started", true);
//commit the changes
editor.commit();
```

and when you start the app you check for that pref

```
//**** next start *****
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
//now we get the saved boolean using the key we previously uesd when setting it
//the second parameter is the default value for the flag in case it was never set
boolean wasAppStarted = settings.getBoolean("pref_app_started", false);
```

//now you can use your wasAppStarted flag to decide what you do further